# preg_match_all get all script tab excluding tabmanager script

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to get all the script that are loaded in my screen

```
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/polyfill.js"></script>


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{"*":{}}
<script>
<script>
    var BASE_URL = 'http://urlm/index.php/';
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US"
    };
</script>

    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KK5JZ25');</script>
```

the code i am using is

```
$conditionalJsPattern = '@(?:<script type="text/javascript"|<script)(.*)</script>@msU';
```

i want to exclude the googletabmanger code
googletabmanger code contains some words like googletagmanager , gtm

how can i do that???

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to get all the script tags added by you and other third-party script but just exclude the google tag manager?

Comment: yes i want that

Comment: @JigsParmar you can try [`(?!.*(googletagmanager|gtm))\s*<script[^>]+?>[\s\S]+?<\/script>`](https://regex101.com/r/SLCdOa/3/)

Comment: Unknown modifier 'g' error

Comment: @JigsParmar don't use `g` flag when you're using `preg_match_all()`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/SLCdOa/4/ check this

Comment: @JigsParmar this is giving what you asked in question isn't it ?

Comment: i am just want to exclude the google tab manger script other all the script is need to seelct script is like <script> or <script type="text/x-magento-init"> or <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: this is my site url http://m2d20.meetanshi.com/ so you can check the script load in the page

Comment: get all the script tags in an array and check if it includes google tag manager if it does just remove it from the array.

Comment: it not work for ous because we want to load all the js after html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this expression might be close to what you have in mind:

```
(<script\b[^>]*>)(?!.*googletagmanager\.com)*?<\/script>
```

and you can flag it however you wish.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xC7tRp/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/xC7tRp/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test

```
$re = '/(<script\b[^>]*>)(?!.*googletagmanager\.com)*?<\/script>/s';
$str = '<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://url/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/polyfill.js"></script>

<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':
new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=
\'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-KK5JZ25\');</script>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: i am not getting you , i update my code can you tell me what regex i have to use to exclude the google tab magener js

Comment: it gives error Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'g'  i use like $conditionalJsPattern = '/(<script\b[^>]*>)([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198981/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-emma).

Comment: only some of the js is select other not

Comment: script is like <script> or <script type="text/x-magento-init"> or <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use should use appropriate tool for parsing HTML (XML in general), regex is very bad idea for that.

But if you HAVE TO use regex, I'd suggest such pattern: `(?s)<script.+?<\/script>`

Explanation:

`(?s)` - single line mode: `.` matches newline

`<script` - match `<script` literally

`.+?` - match one or more of any character (including newline), non-greedy (as least as possible)

`<\/script>` - match `</script>` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TrKqzn/1)

Comment: thank you for your answer but it not exclude the googletagmanager code